# Confused re algorithm running time function simplification

Tags: algorithms

I moved this from stack overflow, as it is probably more a maths than programming related question.

Maths is not my strong point, and the following simplification of a function determining the running time of an algorithm is confusing me:

For a given algorithm:

Let $n$ be the input size

Let $c_i$ be the cost of executing a given statement

$T(n)=c_1n+c_2(n-1)+c_4(n-1)+c_5((n(n+1)/2)-1)+c_6(n(n-1)/2)+c_7(n(n-1)/2)+c_8(n-1)$

I understand the logic that produces this... the confusion lies in the following:

This equation is then expressed as "$an^2+bn + c$ for constants a and b that depend on the statement costs $c_i$."

I have no idea how that follows. I wouldn't ask, but it is important for understanding the order of growth of the algorithm.

Could someone please help!?

EDIT: I had mistyped the expression. It is indeed a quadratic equation. Could someone point me towards a helpful resource for understanding how to simplify equations in this way and the common variable naming conventions? As I say I am very new to maths in general, but studying algorithms requires it!

Comment: Rearranging $T(n) = dn^2 + an + b$, as there are terms in each of those powers of $n$; the coefficients $d$, $a$ and $b$ are linear combinations of the $c_1, c_2, ..., c_8$. That much I hope is obvious. What is not obvious from what you've written so far is that $d = 0$. What do you think?

Comment: Without additional informations about $c_5,c_6$ and $c_7$, $d=0$ does not hold in general.